# Are these lilacs/something else?

Tags: identification, flowers

These started showing up in my backyard this year, I believe they migrated over from my neighbor's yard.  Are they lilacs, or are they something else?  This picture was taken in mid-May in Saginaw, Michigan.

[image: lilacs]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specific flower is [Dame's Rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dame%27s_rocket).  Definitely a mustard, and [apparently commonly confused with phlox](http://trailguidetraining.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/this-week-at-audubon-4/).  Also an [invasive species in Michigan](http://www.mlive.com/news/kalamazoo/index.ssf/2011/06/public_enemy_no_2_invasive_dam.html).

Answer (score 5):

not lilacs, looks to be some sort of mustard... similar to, but not: http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/weeds/plants/blue_mustard.htm